# assigning "socket" to a global class variable returning error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket

I have a class constructor in which I am configuring my **Socket connection** then I am assigning **socket param** to a global class variable i.e. (**this.socket_variable=socket**) so that I can use it globally in other class functions.

**CODE**

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

class WebSocketConfig {
  requestParams = null;
  constructor(server) {
    this.server = server;
    const io = new Server(this.server, {
      cors: { origin: "*" },
    });

    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
      this.socket_variable = socket;

      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("a user disconnected!");
      });
    });
  }

  emitSummaryChannelData = (channelName, data) => {
    this.socket_variable.emit(channelName, data);
  };
}

exports.WebSocketConfig = WebSocketConfig;
```

**PROBLEM**
But when I emit my data using **this.socket_variable.emit()** , it returns error "**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')**".

**things I have tried**
1- I have changed this.socket.emit() to io.sockets.emit() but It does not trigger emit() function at all.
2- then I try to assign IO to a global variable but it did not work either.
3- Try to convert function to arrow function in which I have written this.socket_variable.emit() , but it did not work either

during searching there is a suggestion to update my node version , I am using **Node version v14.17.6**.

Comment: A socket.io callback will NOT preserve your `this` value unless you define the callback as an arrow function, not a regular function.  This is fundamental to how `this` works in Javascript.

Comment: But, I've got bad news for you.  Socket.io servers can field connections from MANY clients so you can't stuff some individual client's `socket` into some shared variable and expect that to work at all.  Each new incoming connection will just overwrite the previous value and you will never know who's `socket` is in the shared variable.  You have to code this completely differently so that you can have many clients connected at once.  socket.io itself keeps track of all connected clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
 io.on("connection", function (socket) {
      this.socket_variable = socket;

      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("a user disconnected!");
      });
    });
```

this.socket_variable is related to internal function not to the class

Comment: I think you are completely right I did not notice it , thanks for pointing that out. Can you please suggest me how to use socket globally , so that I can use its built-in functions in other class functions.